# Isolating CloudWatch metrics for Different Customers

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-tenant, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

Let's imagine a system like below:

- There is a cloud application collecting sensor metrics from various devices and saving these metrics into AWS's CloudWatch.
- These IoT devices may belong to either Customer X or Customer Y.
- A separate organization created for each customer in Grafana. So, they are isolated in terms of their dashboards.

The problem is that the metrics are stored in a common AWS account (even if they are stored in separate CloudWatch namespaces)! So, a member of Customer X can see the metrics of Customer Y by adding a datasource which accesses the namespace of the Customer Y.

Is there a mechanism to have separate credentials to securely isolate CloudWatch namespaces? Or another solution (other than having a separate AWS account for each customer) to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IAM role with [condition keys to limit access to particular CloudWatch namespace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/iam-cw-condition-keys-namespace.html). So each Grafana organization will use own limited IAM role.